# Save cell / range to next row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Edit 2**

```
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results Overview');

  target_sheet.appendRow(get_data_from_Cancellations(ss));
}

function get_data_from_Cancellations(ss) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Cancellations')
  var ranges = [
    [0,1], [1,1], [0,2],    // B1, B2, C1
    [4,3], [5,3], [6,3],    // D5..D7
    [8,3], [9,3], [10,3],   // D9..D11
    [12,3], [13,3], [14,3], // D13..D15
    [16,3],                 // D17
    [18,4], [19,0,20,0,21,0],       // E19, A20
  ];
  var row = make_new_row(sheet, ranges);
  return ['', ...row.slice(0,13), ...new Array(19), ...row.slice(13)];
}
```

Deleted old post, and re-posted here so I can re-word (and hopefully clarify what exactly I'm after)

The script below ‘saves’ the data to another sheet in the specified columns on the next row Available.
I would like to modify this code, so that if there is ANY column on a row that has data, it ignores that row & moves to the next one available.
Essentially, I want the data on the target sheet to go the next available sheet BUT only if the data can stay within the same row as each other.

In the code below & the example screenshot. – If I execute the script, it will put the ‘advisor name’ (Source B1) into Row 9, but the 'reference number' (source B2) will be put into Row 5.
What I would like is the data to go all into row 9. Then the next time all data to go into row 10. So on, and so forth.

**edit** I want the Range `["B1", "B2", "C1", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D17"]` from the sheet "Cancellations", to go into "Results Overview" sheet.
These data ranges should be start to be inputted at the 2nd column, 3rd row. I said in my og post – the range should be inputted at the next available row where there are no cells present in any column in that rar
So the range will all stay within the same row.

```
B1 “Cancellations”>Column B “Results Overview”. 
B2 “Cancellations”>Column C “Results Overview”
C1 “Cancellations”>Column D “Results Overview”
```

So on & so forth

Test spreadsheet link: - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t4rWUd2gJOYR1fS1rPQHu_qh4HNAkbgbbu1OOFgObpc/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

```
 function mytestexport() {
    
    var columnIndex = 2; // Column
      var columnIndexIncr = 1; //columnIndex increment per each target range
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sourceSheets = ["Cancellations"]; //Sheet names
      var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Results Overview"); //Target sheet
      var targetRanges = ["B1", "B2", "C1", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D17"]; //Target ranges
      var sourceData;
      var a1Range;
      var a1Row;
      var targetRange;
    
      for(var range of targetRanges) {
        for(var i in sourceSheets) {
          if(range == "D5") {a1Row = 2} else {a1Row = 2};
          sourceData = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheets[i]).getRange(range).getValue();
            a1Range = targetSS.getRange(a1Row, columnIndex);
            if (a1Range.offset(1,0).getValue() !== "") targetRange = a1Range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).offset(1,0);
            else targetRange = targetSS.getRange((a1Row+1),columnIndex);
            targetRange.setValue(sourceData);
         
        }
        columnIndex += columnIndexIncr;
      }
```

Comment: Looks like you want the `sheet.appendRow()` method.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich How would that be implemented within this script? - Apologies for questions, I'm still trying to learn the basics of app script

Comment: Do not delete and repost... instead edit the original post.

Comment: @Rubén apologies, just wanted to add clarity to what I wanted.

Comment: It's hard to tell, since I'm not quite understand what's going on in your code. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess:

```
function howsitgoing() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheets = ["Cancellations"]; //Sheet names
  var targetSS = ss.getSheetByName("Results Overview"); //Target sheet
  var targetRanges = ["B1", "B2", "C1", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D17"]; //Target ranges

  var new_row = [];

  for (var range of targetRanges) {
    for (var i in sourceSheets) {
      var sourceData = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheets[i]).getRange(range).getValue();
      new_row.push(sourceData);
    }
  }
  
  targetSS.appendRow(['',...new_row]);
}
```

It gathers the data from the `targetRanges` (they are *source* ranges actually, go figure) and append it as a new row at the end of the target sheet.

But if you mean to add the same way into this new row the same ranges from another sheets ('Queries', 'Unanswered') there can be a trouble. The sheet 'Unanswered' has 9 ranges (d5...d15) but sheets 'Cancellations' and 'Queries' have 10 ranges (d5...d17).

**Update**

Here is the code that takes ranges from the three sheets and append data from every of the sheets as a new row at end of sheet 'Results Overview':

```
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results Overview');

  target_sheet.appendRow(get_data_from_Cancellations(ss));
  target_sheet.appendRow(get_data_from_Unanswered(ss));
  target_sheet.appendRow(get_data_from_Queries(ss));
}

function get_data_from_Cancellations(ss) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Cancellations')
  var ranges = [
    [0,1], [1,1], [0,2],    // B1, B2, C1
    [4,3], [5,3], [6,3],    // D5..D7
    [8,3], [9,3], [10,3],   // D9..D11
    [12,3], [13,3], [14,3], // D13..D15
    [16,3],                 // D17
    [18,4], [19,0],         // E19, A20
  ];
  var row = make_new_row(sheet, ranges);
  return ['', ...row.slice(0,13), ...new Array(19), ...row.slice(13)];
}

function get_data_from_Unanswered(ss) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Unanswered')
  var ranges = [
    [0,1], [1,1], [0,2],    // B1, B2, C1
    [4,3], [5,3], [6,3],    // D5..D7
    [8,3], [9,3], [10,3],   // D9..D11
    [12,3], [13,3], [14,3], // D13..D15
    [17,4], [19,0],         // E18, A20
  ];
  var row = make_new_row(sheet, ranges);
  return ['', ...row.slice(0,3), ...new Array(10), 
    ...row.slice(3,12), ...new Array(10), ...row.slice(12)];
}

function get_data_from_Queries(ss) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Queries')
  var ranges = [
    [0,1], [1,1], [0,2],    // B1, B2, C1
    [4,3], [5,3], [6,3],    // D5..D7
    [8,3], [9,3], [10,3],   // D9..D11
    [12,3], [13,3], [14,3], // D13..D15
    [16,3],                 // D17
    [18,4], [19,0],         // E19, A20
  ];
  var row = make_new_row(sheet, ranges);
  return ['', ...row.slice(0,3), ...new Array(19), ...row.slice(3)];
}

function make_new_row(sheet, ranges) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return ranges.map(([row, col]) => data[row][col]);
}
```

**Update 2**

If you want three 'stand-alone' functions (to call them separately from the custom menu, for example), here you go:

```
function get_data_from_Cancellations() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results Overview');
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Cancellations').getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = [
    [ 2,1],                  // B3
    [ 0,1], [ 1,1], [ 0,2],  // B1,  B2,  C1
    [ 4,3], [ 5,3], [ 6,3],  // D5,  D6,  D7
    [ 8,3], [ 9,3], [10,3],  // D9,  D10, D11
    [12,3], [13,3], [14,3],  // D13, D14, D15
    [16,3],                  // D17
    [18,4], [19,0],          // E19, A20
  ].map(([r,c]) => data[r][c]);
  var new_row = [ ...row.slice(0,14), ...new Array(19), ...row.slice(14) ];
  target_sheet.appendRow(new_row);
}

function get_data_from_Unanswered() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results Overview');
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Unanswered').getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = [
    [ 2,1],                  // B3
    [ 0,1], [ 1,1], [ 0,2],  // B1,  B2,  C1
    [ 4,3], [ 5,3], [ 6,3],  // D5,  D6,  D7
    [ 8,3], [ 9,3], [10,3],  // D9,  D10, D11
    [12,3], [13,3], [14,3],  // D13, D14, D15
    [17,4], [19,0],          // E18, A20
  ].map(([r,c]) => data[r][c]);
  var new_row = [ ...row.slice(0,4), ...new Array(10), 
    ...row.slice(4,13), ...new Array(10), ...row.slice(13) ];
  target_sheet.appendRow(new_row);
}

function get_data_from_Queries() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Results Overview');
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Queries').getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = [
    [ 2,1],                  // B3
    [ 0,1], [ 1,1], [ 0,2],  // B1,  B2,  C1
    [ 4,3], [ 5,3], [ 6,3],  // D5,  D6,  D7
    [ 8,3], [ 9,3], [10,3],  // D9,  D10, D11
    [12,3], [13,3], [14,3],  // D13, D14, D15
    [16,3],                  // D17
    [18,4], [19,0],          // E19, A20
  ].map(([r,c]) => data[r][c]);
  var new_row = [ ...row.slice(0,4), ...new Array(19), ...row.slice(4) ];
  target_sheet.appendRow(new_row);
}
```

You still can run all these three functions at once with a main function like this:

```
function main() {
 get_data_from_Cancellations();
 get_data_from_Unanswered();
 get_data_from_Queries();
}
```

Comment: That's great thank you. Yes, I do intend to do the same with ('Queries' & 'Unanswered'), but as their own functions. - So what I would like is for the same thing to happen for 'Queries' but now that row 3 has data, it should input it on the 4 row starting at column 'O'

Comment: I've updated my original post with more info, that will hopefully make it clearer what I'm after

Comment: Should it be one now row for all the tree sheets? Or there should be tree new rows?

Comment: There should be a new row for each three sheets

Comment: Sounds a bit weird, but anyway. See my update

Comment: @YuriKhristich *"Sounds a bit weird, but anyway"*. Don't you think there could also be a menu to run the script? Just a thought

Comment: @marikamitsos of course it makes sense after all, but I have some doubts about the workflow as a whole. Let's wait for the reaction from the asker.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich AMAZING. pretty much exactly what I'm after. - 2 last things I need. 1. For the ‘Audit Type’ in Column D, ‘Unanswered’ & ‘Queries’ are not going into that column. They seem to be going elsewhere. – Can’t figure out how to get them in the proper place. 
2. Can I get A20 from all 3 sheets to go to the AI column on ‘Results Overview’. & E19 for Cancellations & Queries, and E18 for Unanswered to go to Column AH on ‘Results Overview’

Comment: I've just fixed and updated the code. Try it.

Comment: Perfect! - works flawlessly! Thank you so, so much for your help. I've been trying to figure this out for ages. Much Appreciated!!

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry. What do you mean? There is `main()` function that calls the three functions (for three sheets). And there is one more additional function `make_new_row()`. I can remove the additional function if you want. And I can remove the main function, this way you will have three 'stand-alone' functions.

Comment: I just added the examples of three 'stand-alone' functions. Just in case.

Comment: Thank you yet again. Brilliant. - That's me all sorted. Got everything I need. Thank you again!!!! :)

Comment: @YuriKhristich It looks like it works for both of you. On my end though when I run the function: `main()` I get the error: *`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 108, file "MnM")`*. Line 108 reads:  `return ranges.map(([row, col]) => data[row][col]);`. I get similar errors no matter which function I run. Any idea why?

Comment: @YuriKhristich As a quick add-on, would it be possible to take Edit 2 & add another cell? So that B3 from each sheet (e.g. B2 from cancellations) goes to Column A on the ‘Results Overview’?

Comment: I've added 'B3' --> column A in my last variant ('stand-alone functions'). As for the error, I don't understand where the problem is out there. Probably you changed something in your spreadsheet. But I have no access to your updated sheet (Access Denied). Here is the link to my copy of your previous spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ir-u8lXXtPIJQ27vjapt53zS6RXRQ_KWwUY_nh0U6_A/edit?usp=sharing You can try it and see, the script works fine inside this spreadsheet

Comment: It's all working perfectly for me. Thank you get again for the amazing help & support